# Does the CssClassSet class from HtmlElement require checking if the class exists or not?

Tags: dart

I have been doing a lot of:

```
if( item.classes.contains("item") ){
  item.classes.remove("item");
}
```

and similarly:

```
if(! item.classes.contains("item")){
  item.classes.add("item");
}
```

thinking that it would add the string multiple times to the CSS element.

I was curious if I can just call add/remove and it would remove all instance of "item" etc.

I was reading in the class documentation of:  css_class_set.dart and set.dart to follow a bit more into it, and it seems that it does add it multiple times, but maybe i am mistaken.

IE:  I could do something like this:

```
item.classes.add("item");
item.classes.add("item");
item.classes.add("item");
```

and when it reads the classes it would have 3 in there, and then if i remove "item"

```
item.classes.remove("item");
```

it will only remove the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

When reading deeper into it, I forgot the base principle which is used.  This is implementing a set, which can only contain 1 instance of a node at a time.

So in my cases, it would never have more than 1 class called item, and similarly because of that, remove will only ever remove one item (since there is only going to be 0 or 1 items in the Set).

I shouldve looked more into the datastructure at hand before asking this question but for anyone who didnt read deeper into the classes, this is the answer.